# Static c++ libraries aren't found by the .dll of sfml

Tags: c++, dll, makefile, static-libraries, cross-compiling

After quite some straggle I managed cross-compiling a C++ program with sfml from linux to windows. When I run the .exe in the same directory with all the .dlls for sfml I get errors like this:

```
err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\george\\Downloads\\test\\sfml-system-2.dll") not found
err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\george\\Downloads\\test\\sfml-system-2.dll") not found
```

The thing is that I statically linked both libgcc and libstdc++ when I compiled the .exe. How do I make the .dlls to find the libraries? If I statically link them as well will it work?

*My makefile for compiling my .exe:*

```
   #-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -DSFML_STATIC 
   LIBSFML= -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-audio -lsfml-network -lsfml-window -lsfml-system
   CC=$(C32)
   C32=i686-w64-mingw32-g++
   C64=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++

   app.exe: main.cpp
       $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LIBSFML)
```

Comment: You just didn't deploy all of the DLLs you need to run the program.  These are the standard C and C++ runtime libraries, normally present in Linux in /bin.  You get to pick your own bin in Windows, the same directory as your program is a good choice.

Comment: does it have to be dll? I statically linked the libraries but the sfml's dlls didn't see them. Where do I get the dlls for windows? Is there a way to compile them or just download them from somewhere?

Comment: My advice would be to not mix static and dynamic linking, as it will probably be quite tricky to make it work. Link everything dynamic or static. Choose one.

Comment: You should provide more information about your compiler and how you got or built that sfml library. It seems to depend on `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` but for example in debian stretch gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64 compiles executables that work with `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll` and `gcc-mingw-w64-i686` executables that work with `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll`.  If you downloaded sfml DLL from somewhere, it has probably been compiled with a gcc version that has dwarf2 exception handling support, and is probably incompatible with the gcc version you are using.

Comment: @J.J. Hakala yeah that's how it is sadly. Now I'm trying to build the sfml library with cmake. If you have any links to useful tutorials I would appreciate that. I'm using mingw to cross compile sfml for windows. (It doesn't find openal library. >.< )

Comment: **Update:** I managed to build it :D I had to use the pre compiled libraries for the dependencies though. It runs!